# Setting Mysql Index Group columns or separate

Tags: mysql

I have a query `SELECT.. WHERE user_id='' && date>:expire && used=0;`

When I try to create index. should I create all together in one query like

```
CREATE INDEX new_index ON table (user_id, date, used)
```

or should I separate them and create index for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how you plan the query these columns.  Your safest bet would be just make indexes for each column, though this may not yield optimum performance.

Multi-column indexes are useful for cases where:

- You need to enforce a unique constraint across the combination of column values
- You know that you will always uses columns for joins, where clauses, order by, group by, etc. in a specific combination

For example for the combo index you proposed (user_id, date, used) you would be able to utilize the index only in the following conditions:

- You are doing join, where, etc. only on user_id
- You are doing join, where, etc. on user_id and date
- You are doing join, where, etc. on all three columns

You would not be able to utilize the index for these cases

- You are doing join, where, etc. on date or used individually
- You are doing join, where, etc. on date and used

For further reading, here is MySQL documentation on multi-column indexes:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, you should use a multi-column index.  However, the right index is:

```
CREATE INDEX new_index ON table (user_id, used, date)
```

Note that `date` is last in the index, because you have an inequality.

MySQL happens to have a very good discussion [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on multi-column indexes and how they are used.